# How to fetch the number of tasks My Celery App processed

Tags: redis, celery

I've a Celery App which is using redis as a broker and I can fetch the stats of the app using the below command

**celery -A test.celeryapp inspect stats**

This is giving me some numbers like below

```
"total": {
        "test.celerytasks._generate_data": 14493666,
        "test.celerytasks.cleanup_data": 14493,
     }
```

Are these numbers describe that these tasks got executed this many number of times from day1? How to understand these results

How should I get the number of celery tasks which were processed in the last 1 hour/day? Can I get the list of expired tasks in the last one hour/day?

Is there any feasibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> Are these numbers describe that these tasks got executed this many number of times from day1? How to understand these results.

These numbers are the total from the last time celery was restarted.  Essentially, each worker on each node keeps track of its own stats per task and then reports that back to the inspect command, which will then aggregate the results.

> How should I get the number of celery tasks which were processed in the last 1 hour/day? Can I get the list of expired tasks in the last one hour/day?

You can run flower in persistent mode and check the saved state db

Comment: Thank you for your quick help, 
Due to some limitations, I cannot use the `flower` tool, can I achieve my requirement using either redis-cli or celery command line?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  The only options that is lightweight to the app is flower.  You can do heavier weight items like having a custom base task that saves tasks into redis or a common db, but, again, that required modifying the application.

Comment: You can write your own monitoring tool. It is quite simple as Celery provides API for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you DejanLekic, any guidance would be more helpful